# There is some error in my code while using mask in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

1. This is the code

---

```
import numpy as np  
import argparse  
import cv2

ap= argparse.ArgumentParser()  
ap.add_argument("-i", "-image", required= True, help= "Enter path of image")  
args= vars(ap.parse_args())  

image= cv2.imread("2.coin.jpeg")  
cv2.imshow("origional image", image)  
cv2.waitKey(0)  

blurred= cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)  
cv2.imshow("Gaussian blur", blurred)  

(T, thresh)= cv2.threshold(blurred, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  
cv2.imshow("Threshold binary", thresh)  

(T, threshInv)= cv2.threshold(blurred, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
cv2.imshow("Threshold Inv binary", threshInv)  
cv2.waitKey(0)  

cv2.imshow("only cat", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask= threshInv))  
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

2. This is error

---

```
 File "Threshold.py", line 25, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("only cat", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask= thresh))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:245: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'binary_op'
```

https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.shutterstock.com%2Fimage-photo%2Fsouth-african-rands-coins-collection-260nw-493233256.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fsearch%2Fsouth%2Bafrican%2Bcoins&docid=QblUHdnrK9fmmM&tbnid=i8wVEEFiCLTWCM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjntcjTjurkAhVN7nMBHbSxAb0QMwiIAihSMFI..i&w=518&h=280&bih=754&biw=1536&q=coins&ved=0ahUKEwjntcjTjurkAhVN7nMBHbSxAb0QMwiIAihSMFI&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: I don't want to click that link. Please describe what the picture shows. If it is text just replace it by the text.

Comment: It's just a link of coin image. You can take any image to mask and run this code  without error. i use python 3.7 in ubuntu OS.

Comment: Sir please help by solve the problem.